# Does having a single state object cause wasteful rerendering in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I see a lot of articles that mention using a single app store such as Redux for Angular2.  Lets say you have your todoList example component and some other state that doesn't affect the list like a display username.  If you change the username value, then you will get a brand new state object, which would cause the rerendering of the entire todoList.  Isn't this wasteful?

Comment: distinctUntilKeyChanged function does excatly what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370838/ngrx-store-subscription-to-part-of-a-store-and-avoid-detecting-changes-to-other  . Information about distinctUntilKeyChange: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/distinctuntilchanged.md

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. Using patterns like Redux and [Ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/store) for Angular 2 specifically seems to be emerging as a best practice. I'm using it myself, and I don't notice any difference in performance when using Ngrx, even when I'm pulling the state from local data storage.