# @ngrx/store subscription to part of a store and avoid detecting changes to other parts

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

**Background**

One of the reducers in my store deals with things that are selected within the app. The interface for this store (let's called it `app`) could look like this:

```
interface IApp {
    selectedProject: IProject;
    selectedPart: IPart;
}
```

So I want to have a subscription that performs an action only when a different 'project' is selected. I wrote something like this:

```
this.store.select('app')
    .map((store: IApp) => store.selectedProject)
    .subscribe((project: IProject) => {
        // Stuff happens here
    });
```

This function does it stuff when `selectedProject` changes. However, it also does it stuff when `selectedPart` changes. Clearly, it listens to the whole of the `app` store, regardless of the map. That makes sense.

**Question**

I don't want this to happen. I only want my function to execute when `selectedProject` changes.

I know I can split `selectedProject` and `selectedPart` into different stores to solve this. However, I could quickly end up with many, many stores. Maybe this the way it is meant to be?

Is there another way though? Can I keep the store with this interface and have a subscription that only detects changes to the `selectedProject` part of the store?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`distinctKeyUntilChanged`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/distinctUntilKeyChanged.ts).

```
this.store.select('app')
  //Only emit when selectedProject has changed
  .distinctUntilKeyChanged(
    //Key to filter on
    'selectedProject',
    //Optional comparison function if you have a specific way of comparing keys 
    (x, y) => x.projectName === y.projectName)
  .pluck('selectedProject')
  .subscribe((project: IProject) => {});
```